# Manipulate DOM using Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, css, google-apps-script

Is it possible to hide (`display: none`) certain labels and to change the order of the labels in Gmail's drop-down lists ("Labels", "Move") using Google Apps Script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Google Apps Script runs server-side. It does not have access to any DOM elements of Gmail, Calendar, or Sheets, so it cannot apply `display: none;` to them. It can only interact with these services using the [documented methods](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/) which do not include modifying Gmail interface.

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer. Is there any other solution independent of browser extensions?

Comment: It's the same as modifying any other webpage client-side. Userscripts or extensions. Or, [asking Google](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/V_U7zBUZ8G4) to add an option to do this...

Answer (score -1):

Im new to alot of these forms and communities however if im understaning you correctly then you can go into settings area to specify what labels you want to display and hide.

> Load into gmail > click the gear icon[Gear Icon for Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/psJdh.png) > and then click on "See all settings". Above in the tabs you will see labels click there and you will be able to see what im undersatnding your wanting to do with hidding the labels.

And as far as using the DOM or Google Scripts when i helped another company they advised they notivced google uses iframes whitch made it harder for them to work around idea so when we came in to help they had started to just have us not even look in google mail but find another way if possible and so i looked at a few things and advised a possible work around but the results where what they were mainly waniting so i basically thought and advise for them to try to export mail to google sheets where they would or could have us create their frame work displaying their own company UI/ logos etc which then they would be able to use google scripts to run or code as they felt i dont know if that possiblly can help you as well for your project or not but you can reach out anytime if you'd like im structured around the 10th man rule where ever and how ever i can and i get paid to accept the challenge, so goodluck.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32686417)